# Storing dataframe values in a variable in java spark

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

In Spark using java all the result of sqlContext statements are stored in dataframes. I want to compare two consecutive pairs of rows stored in temporary table. Is there a way to iterate through the table in that way? I was planning to have for loop but problem is I can't store row_count in any variable. Can anyone please suggest how I can achieve this?

```
public class ParseResponse implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Search").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc= new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
        DataFrame df1 = sqlContext.read().json("demo1.json");
        df1.registerTempTable("temp1");
        df1.printSchema();
        df1.show();
        DataFrame rows = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) as total_rows from temp1");


    }
}
```

Comment: If you delete the last row of your original dataframe, and create a new (temporary) dataframe without the first row and compares between them, does it works for you? It would be something like df = [x0,x1,..,xn-1] tmp = [x1,x2,...,xn].. A `zip` may help to make the comparison in a single dataframe.

Comment: Thank You Joss for the response. I am looking for any way to iterate through for loop and compare the two consecutive rows in the dataframe, for ex if I have 4 rows then I  have to compare 1&2 , 3&4 rows